# ASP.NET MVC Controller not passing correct value to PartialView using ModelView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a CustomMembershipProvider. When the user clicks the login, I want to display "welcome **UserName**!" inside a PartialView that is contained in the Shared/_layout .cshtml

Here is the controller class:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult WelcomeMessage()
    {
        var userName = this.HttpContext.Session["LoggedInUser"];
        WelcomeViewModel wView = new WelcomeViewModel();

        if (userName != null)
        {
            User user = this.db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
            wView.userId = user.Id;
            wView.Message = user.UserName;

        }
        return PartialView(wView);
    }
```

Here is the PartialView code:

```
    @model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.WelcomeViewModel
    @Html.ActionLink("Welcome " + Model.Message + "!", "Edit", "Account",  new { id = Model.userId })
```

I get the view to render correctly, however when I click the Hyperlink, I am presented with the following error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Details(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.AccountController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

It appears that the Edit Action is called with id = null, however, the user name is displaying correctly. I was initially using ViewBag and have switched to ViewModel as per the SO solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969014/passing-a-value-from-a-viewbag-to-a-partial-view).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The action is `Edit` or `Details`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the wrong [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `@Html.ActionLink`, you need this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
Html.ActionLink("Welcome " + Model.Message + "!", // Display text 
                "Edit",   // ActionMethod
                "Acount", // Controller Name.
                new { Model.Id }, // Route arguments.
                null  // htmlArguments
               )
```

Basically, you need to pass the `htmlAttributes` parameter to hit the right overload, you can pass this as `null` if you don't need to set any.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Welcome " + Model.Message + "!", "Edit", "Account", new { id = Model.userId }, null)
```

The problem is that you set the htmlAttributes parameter of the ActionLink method.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you're using the wrong overload, give this a shot:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Welcome " + Model.Message + "!", "Edit", "Account", 
   new { id = Model.userId }, 
   null)
```